# Rust trait method with default implementation self type is not what is expected

Tags: rust, struct, polymorphism, traits, type-inference

So I have this `FileSystem` trait in rust

```rs
pub trait FileSystem: Debug + Send + Sync
```

And in that trait I have this method here with a default implementation:

```rs
fn location_with_sub_path(&self, sub_path: &[&str]) -> FileSystemLocation {
    FileSystemLocation::new(
        Arc::new(self),
        sub_path
            .into_iter()
            .map(|sub_path_component| sub_path_component.to_string())
            .collect()
    )
}
```

But as you can see here, this method gives an error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Self: FileSystem` is not satisfied
  --> src\file_system_location\file_system\mod.rs:52:13
   |
52 |             Arc::new(self),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FileSystem` is not implemented for `&Self`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `FileSystem`:
             LocalFileSystem
             VirtualFileSystem
   = note: required for the cast from `Arc<&Self>` to `Arc<(dyn FileSystem + 'static)>`
```

The error states that the `self` type does not implement `FileSystem`. `FileSystemLocation`'s constructor takes an `Arc<dyn FileSystem>`, in other words an arc with any object that implements `FileSystem` within.

```rs
pub fn new(file_system: Arc<dyn FileSystem>, sub_path: Vec<String>) -> Self {
    Self {
        file_system,
        sub_path,
    }
}
```

But considering that my default implementation for the `FileSystem` trait is for obvious reasons, only ever going to exist on data types that implement `FileSystem`, I am unsure why rust cannot assume this and compile the code as usual.

I have learnt to realize that almost all of the time, the rust compiler is correct, but clearly I am missing something as I am unsure why this won't compile.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the issue I am facing: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6efc6a1619c6effa37af7991c2a8cc29

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE, and [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: And please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your error message does not match the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message might be a bit misleading — almost surely you want an `Arc<Self>` and not an `Arc<&Self>`? When passing `&self`, if `clone` doesn't exist on `Self` then `self.clone()` just clones the reference through its `Copy` implementation. What you probably want is to pass either `arc_self: Arc<Self>` as the first argument to `location_with_sub_path` and then `Arc::clone(&arc_self)`, or pass `self` instead of `&self` and make sure it can be cloned.